# Ace Editor Unbinding and Re-initiating

Tags: initialization, ace-editor, unbind

I have 2 ace editors in the same interface. Contents are loaded dynamically into the ace editors - on click.

I want to empty the editor in order to clear the screen. But, when I do this, subsequent content will not load into the ace editor.

```
# code used to initiate the ace editor
function initAceEditor(){
var editor1 = ace.edit("editor1");
editor1.setTheme("ace/theme/dreamweaver");
document.getElementById('editor1').style.fontSize='14px';
editor1.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true)
editor1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
});

# code to clear editor div
$('#editor1').empty().attr('class', '');


# I tried the following methods to unbind Ace Editor
ace.edit("editor1").getSession().removeListener('change');

# reinitiated by calling the function
initAceEditor();
```

But the above idea is not working. Note I have 2 editors, I use the same code for editor1 & editor2.

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninitialize and reinitialize, you can destroy your editor's instance which would clean up the entire editor and would avoid any memory leak, and then Call your initialize function.

```
editor1.destroy();
initAceEditor();
```

This would destroy your instance and a create a new one. 
And if you want to remove the DOM nodes and event listeners you are can use:

```
editor1.container.remove()
```

Comment: destroy method did not work for some reason. I used the remove method, which removes the Dom including the div. I used replaceWith to replace parent container structure and used the function to reinitiate ace editor. This method did what I wanted - Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: $('#parent_container').replaceWith('<div id="parent_container"><div......') + reinitializing ace editor worked. editor1.container.remove() was not necessary as replaceWith does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setValue in-order to clear the content.

```
editor1.setValue("");
```

You are trying to clear all the elements present in the div here. Use setValue instead.

Comment: Thank you. I can use this method... I accept this answer even though I still do not know how to uninitialize and reinitialize the ace editor. I would appreciate if anyone could answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying the editor consider just loading another session.

From the howto guide:

```
var js = ace.createEditSession("some js code");
var css = ace.createEditSession(["some", "css", "code here"]);
// and then to load document into editor, just call
editor.setSession(js);
```